# Как сделать ветви диалога бота VK?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, бот

Допустим у бота есть команда 'create', и в ней много параметров, которые нужно указать. Каждый параметр - это отдельное сообщение. И таких команд много. Как сделать ветвление диалогов?
Пример:

```
пользователь: /create
бот: Введи параметр №1
пользователь: 5
бот: Введи параметр №2
пользователь: что-нибудь
...
бот: успешно!
```

и таких ветвей несколько

Answer (score 0):

Если вы делаете через flask, то там есть метод работы с сессиями через использование cookies. Простой пример, сервер считает сколько раз пользователь обращался на сервер(в вашем случае к боту)

```
from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'app secret key'


@app.route('/<login>')
def index(login):
    if 'counter' in session:
        session['counter'] += 1
    else:
        session['counter'] = 1

return {'st': session['counter']}

app.run()
```

Со стороны клиента пишется что то вроде:

```
def url_session():
    url = r'http://127.0.0.1:5000//bob'

    a = requests.get(url)
    print(a.content, '!')
    cookies = a.cookies

    b = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
    print(b.content, '!!')
    cookies = b.cookies

    c = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
    print(c.content, '!!!')
```

При каждом последующем запросе к боту нужно будет сохранять переданные от него куки и посылать их в следующем запросе, тогда бот будет помнить о ваших прошлых ответах.